# Is app update for second In-App-Purchase item registration is not needed?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I just want confirm whether app update for second In-App-Purchase item registration is not needed or not.

It means,

- When I do first time registration of In-App-Purchase item, I understand I need to update the app itself.
- Do I need to update app for additional In-App-Purchase item after the first item released?

As long as I see below message, I think I don't need app review for second time. but let me confirm again.

```
Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First time adding In-App purchase requires review. Adding additional in-app purchases can be added at any time. If you're adding a new in-app purchase type, requires review again.

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1986a0e5c

> After you create an in-app purchase or auto-renewable subscription product in App Store Connect, you submit it to Apple for review. If you are submitting your first in-app purchase, you must submit it with a new version of your app.

> After an app is available on the store with existing in-app purchases, you can submit additional in-app purchase for that app at any time.

> If you are adding a new in-app purchase type to your app (for example, you usually offer consumables, but want to start offering auto-renewable subscriptions), you must do so with app version update.